# Adding a view to subview crashes my application

Tags: objective-c, uiview, crash, subview

When i add a subview it crashes my application. Heres what happens: 
View did load calls a method in another class, that class then calls  sortDataIntoSubs in the original class. That then tries to add a subview, but it crashes as i believe it loops the code which is causing a object out of bounds of array problem. What should i do?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
searchText = [searchText uppercaseString];
self.title = searchText;
Download_Data *dwnLD = [[Download_Data alloc]init];
NSDate *finishDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
dayComponent.day = -1;
NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
startDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:finishDate options:0];
[dwnLD downloadCSVFile:searchText startDate:startDate finishDate:finishDate key:1];
[super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void) sortDataIntoSubs:(NSMutableArray *) arrMTemp
{
NSMutableArray *arrDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrOpen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrHigh = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrLow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrClose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrVolume = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrAdjClose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Add every 7th object to the arrDate array.

[self setUpView];
}

-(void)setUpView
{

CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UISegmentedControl *segMeg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]init];
segMeg.center = CGPointMake(screenBound.size.width / 2,screenBound.size.height / 2);
segMeg.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
NSArray *arrSegMeg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1w",@"2w",@"8w",@"16w",@"25w", nil];
[segMeg initWithItems:arrSegMeg];
[self.view addSubview:segMeg]; //This crashes

}
```

The view is handled by a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing segMeg twice. Try rearranging it like so, and see if it helps:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
NSArray *arrSegMeg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1w",@"2w",@"8w",@"16w",@"25w", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segMeg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arrSegMeg];
segMeg.center = CGPointMake(screenBound.size.width / 2,screenBound.size.height / 2);
segMeg.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
[self.view addSubview:segMeg];
```

Comment: Thanks but no, still crashes.